# Mold or something else?

Tags: mold

What is this, is the mold anyone know?

[image]

Photos: [1](https://ibb.co/0VbPxv0) [2](https://ibb.co/7rmxrqX)
[3](https://ibb.co/Q6pw59q) [4](https://ibb.co/jgKRZB7)
[5](https://ibb.co/64Y7m07) [6](https://ibb.co/M9mdRxb)

Comment: Do you mean the spots at lower right?

Comment: yeah the black spots on the wood

Comment: They look like oil splatter to me. I'm not sure the internet can tell you.

Comment: ah ok, you're not the first to say that (splattered). cheers.

Comment: Try to use a de-greaser on a few spots, and on a few others, try bleach, but not straight bleach). What cleans better? To me, it looks like a splatter and not mold, when looking at it closer. It could also be a "stain" stain/splatter that was wiped and not cleaned before depositing. You could also try sandpaper and see if it comes out....